# PyQt: accessing enabled-state from outside the widget class

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, signals-slots, qwidget

I built a PyQt interface, and now I want to toggle some of its widgets' active/inactive state, or interact with them from outside the widget class.
I have the main-window class with all its widgets, and functions outside the class - here connected to `buttton1`. My goal in this example is to enable `button2` by pressing `button1`.

With the code below, I get the error that my `Ui_MainWindow` class doesn't have the attribute `button1`.

The code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

def toggle():
     Ui_MainWindow.button2.setEnabled(True)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
     def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
         MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
         self.button1 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
         self.button1.clicked.connect(toggle)
         self.button2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
         self.button2.setEnabled(False)
         QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)       

if __name__ == "__main__":

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Until know I have avoided using classes, because honestly, they are very abstract to me. I guess that's why I fail here. I guess I am accessing the widget-class in a wrong way.

I would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction. I read all the answers to similar problems - but it didn't help me to come to a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you designed the ui for your example in Qt Designer, and converted it to a python module using `pyuic4`. What you need to do is import this module into your main script, and then create a `MainWindow` class that loads the ui. If you do it right, all the widgets from Qt Designer will end up as attributes of this class. You can then add methods to the class that control interaction with the widgets.

To begin with, re-generate your ui module and save it as `mainwindow_ui.py`:

```
pyuic4 -o mainwindow_ui.py mainwindow.ui
```

Then create a main script like this:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from mainwindow_ui import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
         super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
         self.setupUi(self)
         self.button1.clicked.connect(self.toggle)
         self.button2.setEnabled(False)

    def toggle(self):
         self.button2.setEnabled(not self.button2.isEnabled())

if __name__ == "__main__":

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Hopefully this code is simple enough that it is self-explanatory. However, if you want some walk-through tutorials, I would recommend you try this:

- [Zetcode PyQt4 tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/)

PS: here is the `mainwindow.ui` file :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>279</width>
    <height>90</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="button1">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Button 1</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="button2">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Button 2</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>279</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: thanks for your instruction. however your example describes referring from a function within the MainWindow-class. how would you do it from a function outside the class?

Comment: @Esmi. You asked to be pointed in the right direction, and that means using methods rather than external functions. If you try to do the latter, writing good gui code can become quite difficult. Do you have a specific reason for wanting to do things that way? What problem are you trying to solve?